# The rank of a smooth function locally doesn't decrease

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $ F\colon \mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^m $ be a smooth map (for your favorite definition of "smooth"). Take some $ p\in \mathbb R^n $ and call $ r $ the rank of the differential $ \mathrm dF(p)\colon \mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^m $ of $ F $ at $ p $.

It's well known that there's a neighborhood $ U $ of $ p $ where the rank of $ F $ does not decrease, i.e. such that $ \operatorname{rk}\mathrm dF(q)\geqq r $ for all $ q\in U $.

The proof relies heavily on the continuity of the determinant. So I was wondering: what if we *don't have* a determinant function? In other words, is this result still true if we work in the category of normed/Banach spaces?

Comment: What do you mean by rank in the (infinite-dimensional) normed space setting?

Comment: OK, I realized that if I assume to work only with functions of finite rank, then everything reduces to the finite dimensional case.